# Como edito los elementos de una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista

Hola tengo la siguiente duda:

Digamos que tengo la siguiente lista de numeros y quiero mostrar los elementos de esta lista uno por uno pero editando la forma en que salen los elementos:

```
telefonos = ["9191211412","6641211412","9941211412","1264511412"]
for x in telefonos:
    print(x[0:2],"-",x[2:6],"-",x[6:10], sep="")
```

Me queda esto y esta bien:

```
91-9121-1412
66-4121-1412
99-4121-1412
12-6451-1412
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer y no me sale, es poner o reemplazar esos resultados en una nueva lista o simplemente en la misma que tenia con el el nuevo formato que me quedo antes con el print. necesito ayuda!!

**EDIT:**

con las respuestas que me dieron lo pude arreglar muy facil asi:

```
telefonos = []
for x in telefonos:
    telefonos.append([f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}"]))
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar el metodo `replace()`?

Comment: no se muy como lo usaria aca, tenes alguna recomendacion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas Python 3.6 en adelante te recomiendo usar literales de cadena formateados, es mucho más eficiente y más legible en mi opinión:

```
telefonos = ["9191211412","6641211412","9941211412","1264511412"]
for x in telefonos:
    print(f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}")
```

Simplemente cada `{}` indica una diana de reemplazo, que es sustituida por el resultado de evaluar la expresión que contiene. El resto, partir la cadena original, es mediante slicing tal y como ya haces.

para crear una nueva lista usa exactamente lo mismo en un `for`, mediante compresión de listas sería simplemente:

```
telefonos = [f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}" for x in telefonos]
```

Ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> telefonos = ["9191211412","6641211412","9941211412","1264511412"]
> >>> telefonos
> ["9191211412","6641211412","9941211412","1264511412"]
> >>> telefonos = [f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}" for x in telefonos]
> >>> telefonos
> ['91-9121-1412', '66-4121-1412', '99-4121-1412', '12-6451-1412']
> ```

La línea anterior es equivalente (aunque mucho menos eficiente) a:

```
telefonos = ["9191211412","6641211412","9941211412","1264511412"]

aux = []
for x in telefonos:
    aux.append(f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}")

telefonos = aux
```

Si quisieras modificarla in-place, usa el índice para reasignar la nueva cadena:

```
for i, tel in enumerate(telefonos):
    telefonos[i] = f"{tel[0:2]}-{tel[2:6]}-{tel[6:10]}"
```

Comment: pero de esta forma: telefonos = [f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}" for x in telefonos] me va reemplazando los resultados, no los va agregando a la lista o no? hice eso y  me quedo perfecto pero solo el ultimo telefono.

Comment: me funciono de esta forma! : telefonos.append([f"{x[0:2]}-{x[2:6]}-{x[6:10]}"])

Comment: FJSevilla sos una especie de bot ? jaj todas tus respuestas son muy buenas y se aprende mucho.

Comment: @TomiBegher sospecho que está usando la linea dentro del for que ya tienes,  pero esa linea se usa tal cual, no dentro de un for. Esa sola linea por si sola ya te crea una nueva lista con todos los items ya formateados. Mira mi edición.

Answer (score 1):

```
 B =[ str(x[0:2])+"-"+str(x[2:6])+"-"+str(x[6:10]) for x in telefonos]
```

De esta manera te sirve?

Answer (score 1):

```
telefonos =  [ "-".join((x[0:2],x[2:6],x[6:10])) for x in telefonos ]
```

Comment: Por favor, añade comentarios explicando tu código. Una respuesta así se considera de 'baja' calidad.